# How can I make this Indexing algorithm more efficient?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, for-loop, indexing

I've got a Dataframe (deriving from a csv file with various columns) with 172033 rows. I've created a custom indexing function that blocks pairs of records that haven't got similar 'name' attributes. The problem resides in the efficiency of the algorithm. Just to get to the 10th iteration it takes about a minute. Therefore indexing the whole dataset would take way too much time. How can I make my algorithm more efficient?

```
class CustomIndex(BaseIndexAlgorithm):
    def _link_index(self, df_a, df_b):
        indici1=[]
        indici2=[]
        for i in range(0, 173033):
            if(i%2 == 0):
                print(i) #keeps track of the iteration
            for j in range(i, 173033):
                if(similar(df_a.loc[i, 'name'], df_a.loc[j, 'name'])>0.5):
                    indici1.append(i)
                    indici2.append(j)
        
        indici = [indici1, indici2]
        return pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(indici, names=('first', 'second'))
```

I want to obtain a MultiIndex object, which would be an array of tuples contains the indexes of the pairs of records which are similar enough to not be blocked.

```
[MultiIndex([(     0,    0),
             (     0,    22159),
             (     0,    67902),
             (     0,    67903),
             (     1,    1),
             (     1,    1473),
             (     1,    5980),
             (     1,    123347),
             (     2,    2),
             ...
```

Here's the code for the similarity function:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
```

Here's an example of the dataframe I have as input:

```
   name
0  Amazon
1  Walmart
2  Apple
3  Amazon.com
4  Walmart Inc.
```

I would like the resulting MultiIndex to contain tuple links between 0 and 3, 1 and 4 and all the repetitions (0 and 0, 1 and 1 etc.)

Comment: There might be ways to perhaps vectorize this, but it's impossible to tell without seeing the whole problem. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not reproducible: we don't know what `similar()` is, and there is no `df_a`, `df_b` small examples provided. Even if you just generate random strings (after `seed(0)` for reproducibility) and show what's supposed to happen, then we could think, experiment, and come up with ideas to speed up your calculation.

Comment: By the way `//` is not a valid comment in Python : this is `#` (I changed it but you reverted the modification).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We asked you to reveal the `similar()` function but you've declined to do so.

You wrote

```
        for i in range(0, 173033):
            ...
            for j in range(i, 173033):
                if similar(df_a.loc[i, 'name'], df_a.loc[j, 'name']) > 0.5:
```

So you plan to call that mysterious `similar` 29_940_419_089 (30 billion) times.
I'm guessing that's going to take some little while, maybe two weeks?
We describe this as O(n^2) quadratic performance.

Here is the way out.

First, sort your dataset. It will only cost O(n log n), cheap!

Next, find something in the `similar` loss function that allows you to
simplify the problem, or design a new related loss function which allows that.
Spoiler alert -- we can only do comparisons against local neighbors,
not against far flung entries more than 100,000 positions away.
I will focus on the five example words.

It seems likely that your mysterious function reports
a large value for `similar("Walmart", "Walmart Inc.")`
and a small value when comparing those strings against `"Apple"`.
So let's adopt a new cost function rule.
If initial character of the two strings is not identical,
the similarity is immediately reported as `0`.

So now we're faced with comparing Apple against two Amazons,
and Walmart with itself.
We have partitioned the problem into "A" and "W" subsets.
The quadratic monster is starting to die.

Minor side note: Since your similarity function likely is
symmetric, it suffices to examine just half the square,
where `i < j`.

A practical implementation for a dataset of this size
is going to need to be more aggressive, perhaps insisting
that initial 2 or 3 letters be identical.
Perhaps you can run a hyphenation algorithm and look
at identical syllables.
Or use [Metaphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone)
or Soundex.

The simplest possible thing you could do is define a
window `W` of maybe 10. When examining the sorted dataset,
we arbitrarily declare that similarity between `i`, `j` entries
shall be zero if `abs(i - j) > W`.
This may impact accuracy, but it's great for performance,
it lets you prune the search space before you even call the function.
We went from O(n^2) to O(n) linear.
Perfect accuracy is hardly relevant if you never wait
long enough for the code to produce an answer.

Use these ideas to code up a solution, and
[let us know](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
how you resolved the details.

---

EDIT

@Pierre D. advocates the use of
[locality sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing)
to avoid lost revenue due to {prefix1}{entity} and {prefix2}{entity}
being far apart in a sorted list yet close together IRL and in hash space.
Metaphone is *one* technique for inducing LSH collisions,
but it seldom has any effect on initial letter / sort order.
[Das, et al.](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/1242572.1242610),
describe a MinHash technique in
"Google News Personalization: Scalable Online Collaborative Filtering".
Number of syllables in the business names you're examining
will be significantly less than size of click-sets seen by Google.
Hashes give binary results of hit or miss,
rather than a smooth ranking or distance metric.
The need to promote neighbor collisions,
while steering clear of the birthday paradox,
makes it difficult to recommend tuning parameters
absent a snapshot of the production dataset.
Still, it is a technique you should keep in mind.

Asking [spacy](https://pypi.org/project/spacy) to do a
[named entity recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition)
pre-processing pass over your data might also be
worth your while, in the hopes of normalizing
or discarding any troublesome "noise" prefixes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the patience, this is definitely the direction I'm going to take. I'm just afraid my dataset might contain names representing the same company that don't start the same way. I haven't encountered similar cases but the dataset is big and I can't examine it all.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how similar() works, I just imported it from the SequenceMatcher class and it uses it's ratio function to find similarity between strings, returning an output between 0 and 1 depending on the similarity.

Comment: I take exception with this answer; it is not correct. For example `SequenceMatcher(None, 'afoobar', 'zfoobar').ratio() > 0.857`, yet `sort` would put them very far apart. In particular, every string starting with `r'[b..y]'` will come in between.

Comment: You came to the conversation late, after certain details like `SequenceMatcher` were surfaced. Recall: "This may impact accuracy, but it's great for performance, it lets you prune the search space before you even call the function. ... Perfect accuracy is hardly relevant if you never wait long enough for the code to produce an answer." Moving away from a two-week elapsed running time was the primary goal. Also, not having seen the full dataset, it's not clear that strings like the pair you mentioned would appear enough times in production data to have an interesting business impact.

Comment: I was actually early in the discussion, then gone on other tasks, waiting for a minimal reproducible example... But that doesn't matter, the point is, If you allow imperfect matching, then at least use something like locality sensitive hashing. Sorting will make the solution incredibly sensitive on the first chars. While it is indeed unclear that 'afoobar' etc. would appear, I've often seen confusion among company names because of articles, e.g. 'The Great Something' instead of 'Great Something'.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.append` method of `list`, that method according to [PythonWiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) is O(1) but *Individual actions may take surprisingly long, depending on the history of the container.*. You might use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) which does have such quirks, just add `import collections` and do

```
indici1=collections.deque()
indici2=collections.deque()
...
indici = [list(indici1), list(indici2)]
```

If that would not help enough you would need `similar` function for possible improvements.

Comment: I think the problem resides in having to check every row (there are 173k) for similarity.

Comment: Indeed. Without insight of what exactly `similar()` does, this is `O(n^2)`. `deque` vs `list.append()` vs list comprehension is only going to change a tiny bit the overall calculation cost.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the solution to your problem requires O(N^2) running time, which means it won't scale well for very large datasets.  Nonetheless, I think there's still a lot of room for improvement.

Here are some strategies you can use to speed up your code:

1. If your dataset contains many duplicate `name` values, you can use "memoization" to  avoid re-computing the `similar` score for duplicate name pairs.  Of course, caching all 172k^2 pairs would be devastatingly expensive, but if the data is pre-sorted by name, then `lru_cache` with 172k items should work just fine.
2. Looking at the [`difflib` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html), it appears that you have the option of *quickly* filtering out "obvious" mismatches.  If you expect most pairs to be "easy" to eliminate from consideration, then it makes sense to first call [`SequenceMatcher.quick_ratio()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.quick_ratio) (or even `real_quick_ratio()`), followed by `ratio()` only if necessary.

3. There will be *some* overhead in the ordinary control flow.

   - Calling `df.loc` many times in a for-loop might be a bit slow in comparison to simple iteration.
   - You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to avoid writing a nested for-loop yourself.
   - BTW, [`tqdm` provides a convenient progress bar](https://tqdm.github.io), which will give a better indication of true progress than the `print` statements in your code.

Lastly, I saw no need for the `df_b` parameter in your function above, so I didn't include it in the code below.  Here's the full solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from functools import lru_cache
from itertools import combinations
from tqdm import tqdm

@lru_cache(173_000)
def is_similar(a, b):
    matcher = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)
    if matcher.quick_ratio() <= 0.5:
        return False
    return matcher.ratio() > 0.5

def link_index(df):
    # We initialize the index result pairs with [(0,0), (1,1,), (2,2), ...]
    # because they are trivially "linked" and your problem statement
    # says you want them in the results.
    indici1 = df.index.tolist()
    indici2 = df.index.tolist()

    # Sort the names so that our lru_cache is effective,
    # even though it is limited to 173k entries.
    name_items = df['name'].sort_values().items()

    pairs = combinations(name_items, 2)
    num_pairs = math.comb(len(names), 2)
    for (i, i_name), (j, j_name) in tqdm(pairs, total=num_pairs):
        if is_similar(i_name, j_name):
            indici1.append(i)
            indici2.append(j)

    indici = [indici1, indici2]
    links = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(indici, names=('first', 'second'))
    return links.sortlevel([0,1])[0]
```

Quick Test:

```
names = ['Amazon', 'Walmart', 'Apple', 'Amazon.com', 'Walmart Inc.']
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': names})
link_index(df)
```

Output:

```
(MultiIndex([(0, 0),
             (0, 3),
             (1, 1),
             (1, 4),
             (2, 2),
             (3, 3),
             (4, 4)],
            names=['first', 'second']),
 array([0, 5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Let me know if that speeds things up on your actual data!

Let's set some realistic expectations.

Your original estimate was ~1 minute for 10 "iterations".  That implies the total time would have been ~6 days:

```
print(math.comb(172033, 2) / (10*172033) / 60 / 24)
```

On the other hand, merely iterating through the full set of `i,j` combinations and doing *absolutely nothing* with them would take ~45 minutes on my machine.  See for yourself:

```
sum(1 for _ in tqdm(combinations(np.arange(172033), 2), total=math.comb(172033, 2)))
```

So the real solution will take longer than that.  Now you've got some bounds on what the optimal solution will require: Somewhere between ~1 hour and ~6 days.  Hopefully it's closer to the former!

Comment: PS -- Note: Since you might be relatively new to StackOverflow, I want to let you know that you are free to unaccept the currently accepted answer and accept this one instead -- if you think this one is closer to what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this is what I came up. After sorting the dataset in alphabetical order according to the attribute 'name', I use this custom index. Every row in the dataset is compared to its neighbours in the range of 100 rows.

```
class CustomIndex(BaseIndexAlgorithm):
    def _link_index(self, df_a, df_b):
        t0 = time.time()
        indici1=[]
        indici2=[]
        for i in range(1, 173034):
            if(i%500 == 0):
                print(i)
            if(i<100):
                n = i
                for j in range((i-(n-1)), (i+100)):
                    if(similar(df_a.loc[i, 'name'], df_a.loc[j, 'name'])>0.35):
                        indici1.append(i)
                        indici2.append(j)
            elif(i>172932):
                n = 173033 - i
                for j in range((i-100), (i+n)):
                    if(similar(df_a.loc[i, 'name'], df_a.loc[j, 'name'])>0.35):
                        indici1.append(i)
                        indici2.append(j)
            else:
                for j in range((i-100), (i+100)):
                    if(similar(df_a.loc[i, 'name'], df_a.loc[j, 'name'])>0.35):
                        indici1.append(i)
                        indici2.append(j)
        
        indici = [indici1, indici2]
        t1 = time.time()
        print(t1-t0)
        return pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(indici, names=('first', 'second'))
```

Indexing the dataset takes about 20 minutes on my machine which is great compared to before. Thanks everyone for the help!

I'll be looking into locality sensitive hashing suggested by Pierre D.

Comment: This requires compromising the accuracy of your results, and 100 seems like an arbitrary constant in this situation...

Comment: If you try my answer on your data (it should work out-of-the-box), a progress bar will appear and it will give you an estimate of what the total running time will be.  I wonder that that estimate says.  If it looks tolerable, then you can have 100% accurate results without waiting days for them to be computed.